# Have lapply continue even after encountering an error using getSymbols from quantmod

Tags: r, error-handling, xts, lapply, quantmod

I am downloading some information from yahoo finance using quantmod wrapped in an lapply statement:

```
require(quantmod)
tickers <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "MKQ", "TSLA")
quotes <- lapply(tickers,function(x) getSymbols(x, src="yahoo", from="2015-02-01", auto.assign=FALSE))
```

The ticker MKQ is made up intentionally. I would like the loop to print the error but still create a list of xts objects with the requested data for the other 3 tickers.

I have tried to use tryCatch as follows but was unsuccessful:

```
quotes <- tryCatch(lapply(tickers,function(x) getSymbols(x, 
src="yahoo", from="2015-02-01", auto.assign=FALSE)) , error=function(e) NULL)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I read the documentation on tryCatch but was not able to make sense of it.

Thank you.

Comment: How were you able to find the duplicate? nrussell, was it because you answered it? I did do a search, but used terms "lapply", "error" and "continue" which are not in the title of the initial post. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `try` block inside your function:

```
quotes <- lapply(tickers, function(x) try(getSymbols(x, ...)))
```

Note we use the simpler `try` here.  If there is an error, your `quotes` object will contain an object of `try-error` class at location of element that caused the error.